# Why does my analyzer disappear when I restart Elastic Search?

Tags: elasticsearch

Full gist at https://gist.github.com/3442562

I have an analyzer:

```
"analyzer" : {
            "lowercase_keyword" : {
                "type" : "custom",
                "tokenizer" : "keyword",
                "filter" : ["lowercase", "trim"]
            }
        }
```

that is referenced in a mapping:

```
"location_countries" : {
                "properties" : {
                    "country" : {
                        "type" : "string",
                        "analyzer" : "lowercase_keyword"
                    }
                }
            }
```

And when I use the 'country' field in a filter or a facet, the field is (correctly) treated as a keyword.

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/clinical_trials/_search?pretty=true' -d '
{
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "brief_title" : "dermatitis" }
    },
    "filter" : {
        "term" : { "country" : "united states" }
    },
    "facets" : {
        "tag" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "country" }
        }
    }
}
'
```

facet results:

```
"facets" : {
    "tag" : {
      "_type" : "terms",
      "missing" : 0,
      "total" : 1,
      "other" : 0,
      "terms" : [ {
        "term" : "united states",
        "count" : 1
      } ]
    }
```

Everything works fine until the machine gets rebooted or the Elastic Search service gets restarted. After a restart, all my filters stop working as if the analyzer does not exist.

The same query against the same data results in:

```
"facets" : {
    "tag" : {
      "_type" : "terms",
      "missing" : 0,
      "total" : 2,
      "other" : 0,
      "terms" : [ {
        "term" : "united",
        "count" : 1
      }, {
        "term" : "states",
        "count" : 1
      } ]
    }
```

If I query the _settings/_mappings of my index, the analyzer and mappings are still defined correctly but the analyzer seems to have no effect.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A removed all the references to pyes as I was able to recreate my problem using curl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The country field appears in multiple nested documents but I am only setting the mapping for one of the fields. After a restart, elasticsearch loads the fields in a different order applies the filter/facet to the wrong field.

Fully qualifying the facet and filter field names fixes my problem.

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/clinical_trials/_search?pretty=true' -d '
{
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "brief_title" : "dermatitis" }
    },
    "filter" : {
        "term" : { "location_countries.country" : "united states" }
    },
    "facets" : {
        "tag" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "location_countries.country" }
        }
    }
}
'
```

Thanks to Clint on the [elasticsearch mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/elasticsearch) for all the help.